# What is the nachash in Genesis 3?

Tags: hebrew

I see that the Hebrew word for serpent in Genesis 3 is nachash and that according to Strongs this word is a noun which stems from the verb 'nachash' meaning to practice divination, or observe signs. Its also the verb used in Genesis 30: 27 when Laban says: "And Laban said to him, “Please stay, if I have found favor in your eyes, for I have learned by experience that the Lord has blessed me for your sake". The words 'learned by experience' is the English translation of nachash.

How does this then explain what the nachash was in Genesis 3? Was Eve 'learning by experience' that the fruit of the tree was desirable? Or was there indeed a physical presence of another kind there persuading her to eat of the fruit? Or is the yetser hara the nachash? Was this conversation between Eve and this nachash one between two beings or a conversation she was having with herself?

The word used for 'said' in this conversation is 'amar' which differs from 'debar'. I suppose this is in itself anther topic, but it does tie in with the nachash question. What is the difference between amar and debar?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Lisa and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!